# Checksum Generators With Advanced Functions

Tags: windows

Checksum generator ExactFile has the function to create checksums for all files within an entire directory and later compare those files with the generated checksum file. (Other checksum generators which I have tried to use do not have the function to compare all files within a directory with their checksum file generated previously.)

However, the latest version of ExactFile seems to be from 2009. Are there any other good checksum generators which include the function to compare all files within a directory with their checksum file generated previously?

Answer (score 2):

With [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) or some other method of running standard Unix tools, you can write a hash file with a command like

```
find | sort | xargs -d '\n' sha256sum > C:/saved-hashes.txt
```

and compare two hash files with `diff`:

```
diff C:/saved-hashes.txt C:/new-hashes.txt
```